# x-editable not working with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I put some partial via sync gem in sync/projects/_list_row.haml

```
%tr
  %td= editable project.name, :name
  %td= project.user_id
```

When I go to edit, I have error:

```
undefined method `asdasd22gh_path' for
```

(the 'asdasd22gh' is project name)
I render partial like this:

```
%tbody
    - @projects.each do |project|
      = sync :partial => 'list_row', resource: project
```

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass you model to the `editable` helper, and the attribute name:

```
%tr
  %td= editable project, :name
  %td= project.user_id
```

The first argument in the `editable` helper is used to build the url, using `polymorphic_path` function. Since you pass a string there, he takes the string as the route name.

Comment: Could you explain this with little example ? :)

Comment: Sure, I added an explanation to the answer :)

Comment: Eh :/ I don't know why I have 'undefined method for' When I type `%tr
  %td= editable project, project.name`
Also for `= editable project, :name` -> error is 'undefined method `xeditable?' for '

Comment: Ok. I just don't add helper to applicationhelper. Thank's Yury !